# how to enable sound support in linux kernel without recompile?

Tags: linux, kernel, compiling, drivers

I have recently compiled linux kernel 3.2. But at time of compiling in make menuconfig, I had disabled sound support.

Now, I want to enable it without recompile it. I don't want to use stock kernel or direct kernel image, I always wanted to use compiled kernel.

Comment: If you didn't compile sound support, you'll need to compile it. Or use another kernel. There's no magic, if you don't have the modules, you can't have  what they provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`make menuconfig` and enable it as a module. Then, `make modules_install`, which compiles and installs modules, should do the trick. Though you wil not need to compile whole kernel, you will have to compile modules. At least on Gentoo.

You haven't mentioned what distro you are using. May be someone else could provide better answer.

Tip: configuration of running kernel can be found in `/proc/config.gz` (Usually, this feature is enabled).